# Select from another table if result not matched

Tags: mysql

This has been asked but I dont quite match existing questions with my case. 
I have two tables, the first table is `credentials` with `id` `username` and `email`

and an `email-alias` table with  `user-id` (which corresponds to `credentials.id`) and `email`. Emails in `credentials` are more often "user.name@domain.com" while in alias they'd be "usern@domain.com".

All I have now is

```
SELECT `username` FROM `credentials` WHERE `email` LIKE ?
```

But the email will not always match if I query with "usern@domain.com". What I want to do is get the username with one query which would fall back to `email-alias` and use "usern@domain.com" to get an `user-id` from there to be used again in `credentials` to match a `username`

The pitfall is that the supplied email could be either an aliased one "usern@.." or "user.name@.."

```
mysql> describe `email-alias`;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user-id | int(11)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| email   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe `credentials`;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| username        | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                |
| email           | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: To be honest, this is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is kind of confusing but I think what you're trying to do is select `username` from the first table if the `email` exists and if it doesn't select from the 2nd table if it exists. You would use subqueries for that. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT `c.username`
FROM credentials c
WHERE c.email = 'usern@domain.com' OR c.id = 
(SELECT `e.user-id` from email-alias e WHERE e.email = "usern@domain.com")
```

Comment: Yes this seems more probable. With ORs being evaluated left to right it won't always have to do the second query I think

Comment: Yes this also works if the email is aliased (that is the nested query had to run)

Comment: It does directly and that's why I mark it as accepted but check my comment to the other one too

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question clearly because it's too confusing. But let me give this a try. You need to join the table using `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT  `username`
FROM    credentials a
            INNER JOIN email_alias b
                on a.ID = b.userID
WHERE   b.email = 'usern@domain.com'
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  `username`
FROM    credentials a
            INNER JOIN email_alias b
                on a.ID = b.userID
WHERE   b.email LIKE '%usern@%'
```

Comment: Yes this works fine if the supplied email parameter is an alias address but I don't think it would work if the email isnt an alias which is also a possibility

Comment: Well unfortunately I cant test with an email thats not alias now, but if it's an alias it works. Saw the edit the domain matching isn't a great issue

Comment: I could test ofc I just had to change the credentials and alias tables to simulate different addresses derp.. This will become complete by simply adding `OR  a.email LIKE '%usern@%'` to check the other one as well, I've tested